# Neo4j Load CSV Errors Galore

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, load

I have tried all variations on the following and have combed through and tried the many solutions offered to similar problems posted here. 
I try:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "file:///C:/neo/coordinates.csv" 
AS Line
CREATE (c:Church {id: toInteger(Line.id), name: Line.name, address: toInteger(Line.address), city: line.city, state: toInteger(Line.state) long: toInteger(Line.long), lat: toInteger(Line.lat), g: toInteger(Line.g)})
```

and get errors like this -

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'l': expected whitespace, comment, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', '~', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or '}' (line 4, column 140 (offset: 209))

Help? I'm rather new to this. Oh, and I'm on windows 10. Thanks!

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. The only thing is, I'm not even able to get the CSV data using `LOAD CSV FROM 'https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/csv/artists.csv'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a comma(,) before the property long.

In this part:

> state: toInteger(Line.state) **,**  long: toInteger(Line.long)

Also, change **line** to **Line** here

> city: line.city

**I am adding the query with corrections here:**

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "file:///C:/neo/coordinates.csv" 
AS Line
CREATE (c:Church {id: toInteger(Line.id), name: Line.name, address: toInteger(Line.address), city: Line.city, state: toInteger(Line.state), long: toInteger(Line.long), lat: toInteger(Line.lat), g: toInteger(Line.g)})
```

Comment: OK. All my experimenting created those added typos you corrected. Thanks, but now I'm back to :  Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input: expected whitespace, ')' or a relationship pattern (line 4, column 216 (offset: 285))
"CREATE (c:Church {id: toInteger(Line.id), name: Line.name, address: toInteger(Line.address), city: Line.city, state: toInteger(Line.state), long: toInteger(Line.long), lat: toInteger(Line.lat), g: toInteger(Line.g)}"
The carrot points to "lat:" removing or altering statements still nets "invalid syntax". tried "set" for props - same

Comment: Hey, I forgot my final ")" ! Hahaha, all's well now. Also browser wasn't looking where I pointed it and needed to put my csv into the neo4j/import folder. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, I got ahead of myself. Nodes and labels, but no  properties are loading. Think I got a formatting issue with my csv file. Github example loaded just fine.... How do I "accept the answer"?  Thanks, again

Comment: Can you share the sample data you trying to load?

Comment: Raj, It loaded, it had a couple of typos a csv validator (didn't know there was such a thing) caught for me. Now I'm trying to csv load relationships.  My nodes represent 80 priests and 200 churches. I am trying to do this - which works: MATCH (p:Priest{name: "Baranowski, Alexander Sylvester" }),(c:Church{name: "St Wenceslaus"}) 
MERGE (p)-[:POSTED {posting:'1955-61', zip: '60618'}]->(c) , but with 800 rels, My csv sheet has priests listed perhaps 10x each connected  to 10 different churches. My rels are years and zip codes. Nothing I have read and tried has worked. Ideas? Thanks again!